# How can I create multiple dateframes consisting of columns from an existing df with a loop [Pandas, Python]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to create multiple dataframes based on the columns of an existing dataframe. To keep the code simple and scalable, I used a loop. This is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

for index in range(df.shape[1]):
    df_index = df.iloc[:, [0, index]]
```

The output of the above code is one dataframe consisting of the first and last column of the dataframe. The **desired output is multiple dataframes that consist of the first column and the index in a single iteration**.

The dataset I am using consist of 85 columns. The desired output would consist of 85 dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should look like this

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []

for index in range(df.shape[1]):
    dfs.append(df.iloc[:, [0, index]])
```